# Moto G 4- Call ended when I start calling

Tags: motorola-moto-g-4g

I have a trouble with my Moto G4! When I tried call someone my cellphone start calling and after 5 seconds it ened the call! I remove my SIM CARD and put it in another cellphone it happened too!

Can someone help me?

Comment: _I remove my SIM CARD and put it in another cellphone it happened too!_ - You have put your SIM in another phone, and the problem persists? It is a problem in your SIM CARD...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I think so! What would I do? Go to the Support Center of my SIM Company? :)

Comment: Once I had a problem with my SIM (related to internet connection) - I requested a new one from the company (with the same number), and it fixed it... Maybe it does the trick for you...

Comment: Is it possible that you are hanging the call with your cheek? or part of your face? or that it has enabled a feature that when it doesnt detect light (as when you put it face down on flat surface) it goes to sleep or hangs? check that out.